# Sub test() Dim z As String For z = 14 To 17 For b = 14 To 17 ActiveSheet.Cells(b, 13) = "z" Next z Next b End Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am quite the noob.  I am trying to get a variable to work within quotation marks while looping. For example:

```
Sub test()
Dim z As String
For z = 14 To 17
For b = 14 To 17

ActiveSheet.Cells(b, 13) = "z"

Next z
Next b

End Sub
```

I get a "Compile error: Type mismatch".  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please edit your question and use a few words of explanation as the title of your question, not code. Take a moment to familiarize yourself with how this place works. It's explained in the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

You declare the variable `z` as a string. Strings are not numbers and cannot be incremented or used in `for` loops.

Declare the variable as an integer and print the value into the cell.

The outer z loop is closed before the inner b loop. That is a problem, too. You may want to get used to indenting your code to make such errors more apparent.

Overall, it is not clear what you want to achieve. If you just want to print the z value into a range you don't need the b loop at all, for example:

```
Sub test()
Dim z As Integer

For z = 14 To 17
' enters z value into column M
    ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 13) = z
Next z

End Sub
```